# How to disable load these css in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The website is always browse by Chinese and they can't access google,
I'm using wordpress design the website and I think the theme include google fonts api and other css inside.
How can I disable load the css while the user in China?

These css load take long long time.
I test the website in HK it's fine but in China it very slow
Please help
Many thanks!
[image]

Comment: it depends on how they are loaded. in general you would use `wp_dequeue_script` and `wp_dequeue_style` functions for this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/

Comment: Thank you very much , I will try it later! Thanks